# Resetting nesting level of csquotes within reledmac macros

Tags: csquotes, reledmac

The `csquotes` packages states in the documentation under 10.7, that
"This package will automatically reset the nesting level within any footnote included in a quotation."

It really works. When using `reledmac`, however, this reset is not applied. Looking at the source code of  `csquotes` I could not manage to find the appropriate macro to add to e.g. `footnoteA`.

So, what do I have to add to reset the nesting level of `csquotes` manually?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}
\enquote{This is an example\footnote{Better say \enquote{example}}} and
this one now with \enquote{reledmac\footnoteA{\enquote{A great package btw}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The standard \footnote calls `\@parboxrestore` and csquotes hooks into it to reset the level. You could simply add `\csname csq@qlevel\endcsname=0\relax` to the footnoteA code.

Comment: Thank you. As I use a surrounding macro anyway, I was able to add your code quite easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard `\footnote` calls `\@parboxrestore` and `csquotes` hooks into it to reset the level.

If you want to reset the level manually you can add

```
  \csname csq@qlevel\endcsname=0\relax
```

to the `\footnoteA` code.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer code, this feature has been integrated directly on reledmac 2.19.0 (which I will send in CTAN in few minute).